# Failover NIC with Windows 7 running Apache Server

Tags: windows-7, networking, apache-http-server, network-adapter

I have a Apache Server running on a Windows 7 Desktop for a internal website (Intranet). I am trying to figure out how I can make this system as failover safe as possible. One thing I want to do is use the 2nd NIC card that is currently disable. I only have one gateway address to my router. I do not have any computer running a Server O/S.

If NIC1 crashes by chance(just humor me!), how could NIC2's IP take on the host name (I have mapped in host file) . I don't really care if the static IP of NIC2 changes seeing that the host name is the only thing I need.

Could I add two IP's to the host file, with same host email and maybe create some script that will run IF NIC 1 fails?

OR is there any failover software that will do this for me?

Comment: I see there is NIC teaming, but only for Windows 8.1 & 2012. hmm

Comment: UPDATE! I guess what I want is network link aggregation, which is built into Windows 7.http://www.ehow.com/how_10004367_setup-nic-teaming.html . However if I add NIC2 IP to host file, will browser still see NIC2 IP address attached to Hostname ? I know DNS Server would work, but I don't think there's a light & free DNS Server to use on a Windows 7 Desktop.